# how to select distinct values from two tables limit to one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with this values:

```
**table 1**    
id name value
1   A     1
2   B     1
3   F     2
4   G     3

**table 2**
id name value
1   C     1
2   D     1
3   E     2
```

If I do an inner join of both tables by the value I´m getting this:

```
A C
A D
B C
B D
F E
```

But, the problem is that I want only distinct values from both columns like that:

```
A C
B D
F E
```

Another set of posible result will be:

```
A D
B C
F E
```

There´s no chance of name of table 1 will appear in table 2.

If one value from a column was already selected, it can´t be selected again. This example will be an error because C was already selected:

```
A C
B C
F E
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is A D and B C equally good result? Does it matter?

Comment: I tried with select least(a.name, b.name), greatest (a.name, b.name) but no result. select distinct not working...

Comment: yes! AD and BC will be a good result too. Another combination with unique values.

Comment: perhaps you should add additional data to your test data and expected results... what happens if the same `name` exists in both table 1 and table 2?  At this point I'm not very clear on what you're looking for.

Comment: @Kritner there´s is no chance of name exist in both table. I edit and put some more data.

Comment: also consider creating this as a sqlfiddle, i'm not familiar enough with oracle syntax to do so

Comment: @Kritner Yes, i want a combination of both columns with distinct values. If I have all data in one table also need and inner join with itself to match the value field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to pair the records, you need a running number per value to link with. Use row_number() for this.

```
select t1.name as t1_name, t2.name as t2_name
from
(
  select name, value, row_number() over (partition by value order by name) as rn 
  from table1
) t1
join
(
  select name, value, row_number() over (partition by value order by name) as rn
  from table2
) t2
on t1.value = t2.value and t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75de0/1.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the data you provided, and the column you're using to join, you're getting the results you should be getting.

To get your desired results, you would need to join on `id`, not `value`

as such:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.name
from tableA a
inner join tableB b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: This was a set of values as an example. I need to do the inner join with the value, not by id, and obtain a combination of diferents values from each column.